# Get jQuery validator object from within the submitHandler function

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am attempting to call the jQuery validation `showErrors` function from within the `submitHandler` function without having to saving the validator object like so:

```
var validator = $( "#myshowErrors" ).validate();
validator.showErrors({
    "firstname": "I know that your firstname is Pete, Pete!"
});
```

Is there a way to get the get the validator object from within the `submitHandler` method somewhat like this:

```
$( "#myshowErrors" ).validate({
  submitHandler : function(form) {

    $(form).ajaxSubmit({
      success : function(result) {

        var validator = // Get validator here somehow?
        validator.showErrors(result.fieldErrors);

      }
    });

  }
});
```

By doing it this way, my hope is that I can use the same `submitHandler` method in multiple places throughout my project.

Comment: There are so many methods available to customize the usage of this plugin.  But you can't use the `submitHandler` anywhere outside of `.validate()`.  And why would you need to put `showErrors` inside of the `submitHandler` callback function?

Comment: Please give a concrete example about what you're trying to achieve so it can be placed into a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y95gk/).  Then I'll be able to tell you if it can be done better using the standard options and callback functions.

Comment: Regarding edited OP:  This still doesn't make any sense.  [By definition](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate), the `submitHandler` callback function only fires when the form is "valid"... what use is `showErrors` at this point when a valid form will have no errors?

Comment: I want to use the submitHandler to render errors that occur from a server response. I use the `submitHandler` method to submit the form via AJAX. However, although the form data may be valid on the front-end, it still may have invalid data once I go to process it. For example, I'm validating a user's address on a the server to see if it exists (using a 3rd party API). If there is an error during serve-side validation, I would like to to display these errors in the same manner using the jQuery validate to make client-side and serve-side validation appear seamless.

Comment: That's what the `remote` method is for.  See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/

Comment: @Sparky: I've actually found it useful to show server side errors with jQuery validate. You get some nice things like the error messages disappearing when the user changes the value, error placement code that gets reused, etc.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker, don't you also get these things using [the `remote` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/)?

Comment: I am familiar with the `remote` function. However, passing additional field values to the remote method is cumbersome and much uglier than simply submitting the form data and then using `showErrors` for field errors returned by the server. `remote` is also not a good option for many of my cases where I am processing credit card payments and I receive error codes from the payment gateway. Since the errors I would receive from the payment gateway occur during payment processing, `remote` is not an option.

Comment: @Sparky: Yes, but sometimes you need the submission as a whole to evaluate whether a particular field is valid or not. I use the `remote` option if a field can be evaluated without context (the classic "email is in use" example). This is just personal preference though. I suppose you could validate everything using a remote rule, but you're going to have to validate the request again on the server anyway right? Why not pipe the results of *that* validation back to jQuery validate?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker Exactly!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Validator object is stored in form element data:

```
var validator = $.data( form, "validator");
```

**Edit:**

In fact validator should be also stored in `this`:

```
$( "#myshowErrors" ).validate({
  submitHandler : function(form) {
    var validator = this;

    $(form).ajaxSubmit({
      success : function(result) {
        validator.showErrors(result.fieldErrors);
      }
    });

  }
});
```